# Regex validation in Cocoa Touch

Tags: ios, regex, cocoa-touch, nsregularexpression

Is there an equivalent to `pattern.compile()` for regexes in Cocoa Touch? Is it possible to check if the given regex expression is error-free? Will `NSRegularExpression`'s `NSMatchingInternalError` handle this test case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pattern.compile()` equivalent would be: `regularExpressionWithPattern:options:error:`.

As an example:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *pattern = @"[z-a]";
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
if (re == nil) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}
```

returns the error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=2048 "The value “[z-a]” is invalid." UserInfo=0x100111f90 {NSInvalidValue=[z-a]}

It looks like `NSMatchingInternalError` can be generated during the matching operation, not during creating the RegEx.

Comment: I tried a bad regex and got : The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 2048.)